# Is it okay to repost my relevant Stack Overflow questions on Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, serverfault, cross-posting

I've reposted a couple questions I originally posted on SO that seemed too server-y even at the time. It seems a bit silly to repost, but they're more suited to Server Fault. Is this frowned upon?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Voting to close as "Belongs on Uservoice"

Comment: Doesn't really belong on uservoice, thats more for feature suggestions, this is more of an FAQ type question

Answer (score 12):

Don't just re-post them. Instead, vote to close them as "belongs on serverfault.com". In order to help you gather the necessary votes (and to prevent vote wars), edit the original question and make it clear that you are the original author and that you *wish* it to be moved here.

Comment: Yeah, don't repost it, get it moved. That's why the option exists.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. In fact - I think the admins want you to repost your question here.

Because Joel and Jeff want serverfault.com to be the sort of place which holds the answers to all server questions, I think they'd be happy to have questions answered at other sites to be reposted here.

The best use-case that Joel talks about is asking a question on stackoverflow.com and having the answer instantly pop up. By asking the question again here, you're moving the information to where it deserves to be.

Probably - To avoid stepping on toes, I'd ask for the original question to be closed. You're not flooding all sites with your question - You're just putting the right question in the right place.

Answer (score -2):

**Definitely re-post here**

I think the idea is to make this database as complete as possible - and being off-topic on Stack Overflow will keep them from being as highly viewed, since the audience is different.